# Using Heroku for static site: Assets won't show

Tags: ruby, image, heroku, rack, static-site

I've just loaded up a static app to Heroku using [this tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/static-sites-ruby) and everything works quite well, except my images aren't showing up. When the same site is hosted on my own server as a plain static site (not through Heroku), all of the assets load up without a problem.

Currently, I have a Gemfile, Gemfile.lock, app.rb, config.ru and public (static site directory) in my repository that I'm loading to Heroku through `git push heroku master` to push to Heroku.

My images are in public/img and even the assets directly referenced from html aren't showing up. When I use firebug lite in Chrome to check the asset directory, it seems as though the image files are there, but they don't seem to have the image data (from what I could tell).

I do not have any further ruby/rails files. Should I have a production.rb file somewhere? Am I missing out on something?

Currently, my setup on Heroku is the free package. Will I need to upgrade to a paid package to see my assets (I only have 2MB of assets)? I've tried creating an "assets" directory inside the "public" directory and placing the img directory in there, but still no luck.

Here is my config.ru

```
use Rack::Static, 
  :urls => ["/img", "/js", "/css"],
  :root => "public"

run lambda { |env|
  [
    200, 
    {
      'Content-Type'  => 'text/html', 
      'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=86400' 
    },
    File.open('public/index.html', File::RDONLY)
  ]
}
```

Comment: What do your logs say?

Comment: @CodeGnome My logs don't provide me with anything useful. Its just filled with get calls on my files and 0 errors. One example is `at=info method=GET path=/img/logo.png host=myApp.herokuapp.com fwd=99.231.162.16 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=1ms service=6ms status=200 bytes=16190`

Comment: @CodeGnome Oh. I just read something that is a little bothersome. Heroku requires assets to be hosted on S3? Isn't that excessive for a static site? How would I even do that, other than direct links without utilizing the ruby gem for S3?

Comment: Heroku recommends something like S3 for backing. It does not require this.

Comment: @ctshryock So, how should I be hosting/accessing my images? Its just a basic html/js/css site with 2MB of images.

Comment: can you share your config.ru file? /img/ doesn't seem to match the guide you linked (it suggests /images/

Comment: link to your app? does `img/logo.png` work, instead of `/img/logo.png` ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24535/discussion-between-rileye-and-ctshryock)

Answer (score 2):

To diagnose issues like this where you believe the file contents on your dyno don't match the ones in your source, use `heroku run bash` to login into a remote, [on-off dyno](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos). This will drop you into a bash shell where you can explore the file system as seen by your dyno (although the dyno your shell is attached to is not the one actively serving your requests it will have the same filesystem contents).

```
$ heroku run bash
Running `bash` attached to terminal... up, run.4065
~ $ ls
pubic Gemfile Gemfile.lock app.rb config.ru
~ $ cd public/img
~/public/img $ ls -l
total 40
-rw------- 1 u36831 36831  2743 2013-02-15 18:54 facebook-1652d049.png
-rw------- 1 u36831 36831  2291 2013-02-15 18:54 feed-e8d78a2f.png
```

From here you should be able to see:

- If the image files even exist on the dyno
- If their contents are what you expect (do the file sizes match what you see in your local env?)

Comment: I've done all of that and all of the sizes are as they should be. I'm still very confused as to why the images aren't showing up.

Comment: What's the app name/URL? And is the repo public?

Comment: The URL is http://shielded-taiga-6010.herokuapp.com. The repo isn't public, but the site is completely static.

Comment: It looks like images are being served now? http://shielded-taiga-6010.herokuapp.com/img/proj-bantr-screen1.png What changed?

Comment: That's too weird. Nothing has changed. Maybe they weren't able to be uploaded for a few days? I guess I can revert the image calls now.